# Bootstrap form labels in mobile decrease in size when input text gets focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in a web page that uses Bootstrap class, sample is below:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="passwordclass="form-control" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

On mobile, the form initially displays as I hoped it would. The form elements are stacked vertically.

But when I tap on the username or password input boxes, the labels would decrease in size. How do I keep the label text size as is?

Thanks

Comment: You sample code has errors you are missing "

Comment: Are you missing the viewport `<meta>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working fiddle that work nice
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9094/

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" 
            placeholder="Enter First Name">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" 
            placeholder="Enter Last Name">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" name="submit" />
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the viewport of the meta tag, the attribute/ value content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" was added. The complete meta tag is now:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This seems to have solved the problem. On mobile, when I tap on on input entry, all label font sizes are retained